# shell script to count readable files

Tags: bash

How can I write a shell script file_readable which:

- accepts some number of names as arguments,
- checks each name to see if it is a regular file and readable, and
- outputs a count of the number of such files.

For example:

```
$ sh file_readable /etc/fstab /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key /etc/does-not-exist
1
```

Of these, only `/etc/fstab` is likely to both exist and be readable.

So far I have put this together but it does not work correctly - can anybody help me please ?:

```
#!/bin/sh

for filename in "$@"

do
        if test -f "$filename"
        then  echo | wc -l
        else echo $?
fi
done
```

Comment: This site doesn't exist to solve tasks you are given. It exists to help you with concrete problems you are facing. Do not just dump a task description here and expect someone to do it for you for free ...

Comment: Seems like OP have a concrete problem. Just not well formulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `then  echo | wc -l`

If file exists and is a regular you print number of lines in empty string plus "\n", which is equal `1` always. Sound not quite usable, isn't it?

All you need is incrementing some counter and printing it in the end.

```
#!/bin/sh

readable_files=0
for filename in "$@"; do
    if test -f "$filename"; then
        readable_files=$(( readable_files + 1 ))
    fi
done

echo "${readable_files}"
```